# Writing a generic Scala merge function, can't get types to line up for compiler

Tags: scala, generics

I'm trying to learn FP with Scala. I've got a function on an object to merge two sorted collections and return the same type. It looks like this:

```
@tailrec def merge[A, Repr <: Seq[A]](merged: Repr, l1: Repr, l2: Repr)(
  implicit ordering: Ordering[A]): Repr = {
if (l1.isEmpty) merged ++ l2
else if (l2.isEmpty) merged ++ l1
else {
  val l1Head: A = l1.head
  val l2Head = l2.head
  val orderVal = ordering.compare(l1Head, l2Head)
  if (orderVal <= 0) {
    val m2: Repr = l1Head +: merged
    merge[A, Repr](m2, l1.tail, l2)
  } else {
    merge[A, Repr](l2Head +: merged, l1, l2.tail)
  }
 }
}
```

It's giving me the compiler error "Expression of type Seq[A] doesn't conform to the expected type Repr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
@tailrec def merge[A, Repr](merged: Repr, l1: Repr, l2: Repr)(implicit
  ev: Repr => SeqLike[A, Repr],
  cbf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, A, Repr],
  ordering: Ordering[A]
): Repr = {
  if (l1.isEmpty) merged ++ l2
  else if (l2.isEmpty) merged ++ l1
  else {
    val l1Head: A = l1.head
    val l2Head = l2.head
    val orderVal = ordering.compare(l1Head, l2Head)
    if (orderVal <= 0) {
      val m2: Repr = l1Head +: merged
      merge[A, Repr](m2, l1.tail, l2)
    } else {
      merge[A, Repr](l2Head +: merged, l1, l2.tail)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That works! Unfortunately now that I can test my code it doesn't do the right thing... but at least now I can test it!