# Creating an empty IndexedSeq of a sub-type and using TailRec

Tags: scala, generics, recursion

Following up on my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55343336/writing-a-generic-scala-merge-function-cant-get-types-to-line-up-for-compiler), I have a mergeSort function which takes a subclass of IndexedSeq[A] and sorts it using that merge() function.

```
def mergeSort[A, Repr <: IndexedSeq[A]]
    (l: Repr)(implicit ev: Repr => SeqLike[A, Repr],
                       cbf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, A, Repr],
                       ordering: Ordering[A]): Repr = {
  if (l.length <= 1) l
  else {
    val (left, right) = l.splitAt(l.length / 2)
    merge[A, Repr](IndexedSeq.empty[A], mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right))
  }
}
```

How do I :

1. Create an empty instance of the Repr type?
2. Use the scala.util.control.TailCalls._ package to make it tail call recursive?

Comment: Can you add code of `merge`?

Comment: See the link above the code

Answer (score 1):

Not fully tested, and I'm not convinced that this actually achieves your TailCall goal, but it compiles.

```
import scala.util.control.TailCalls._

def mergeSort[A :Ordering, C[_]](l: C[A])(
  implicit ev :C[A] => SeqLike[A, C[A]],
          cbf :CanBuildFrom[C[A], A, C[A]]) :TailRec[C[A]] =
  if (l.length <= 1) done(l)
  else {
    val (left, right) = l.splitAt(l.length / 2)
    for {
      tcl <- tailcall(mergeSort(left))
      tcr <- tailcall(mergeSort(right))
    } yield merge(l.drop(l.length), tcl, tcr)
  }
```

You'll have to call `.result` on the final return value from `mergeSort()`.

Comment: `l.drop` is a pretty creative replacement for `cbf().result` :D

Comment: Isn't l.drop(l.length) an O(n) operation?

Comment: not for `IndexedSeq`, at least, it shouldn't be. `l.take(0)` may be a safer alternative. 
But the "right" way is `cbf().result`. That would be the only use for `cbf` here either way, you don't need it for anything else